# How to split string in javascript while working on mongodb

Tags: javascript

I'm working on MongoDB to get some output and for that I'm writing javascript to pass to mongo shell.

I have one object where one field name **intetions** is an array of some IDs and format of those IDs are as follows

DBRef("Intention", ObjectId("5a3247206e4dee78d74b9e91"))

I have to get 5a3247206e4dee78d74b9e91 from above entry to pass it to some other queries.

my script is as follows

```
var cursor = db.coll.find({_id: "797276b3-d86b-48cd-ac1d-5d15ccd776da", "accountId" : "abc"})
cursor.forEach(function(w){
    id=w._id;
    title=w.title;
    response=w.message;
    intentions = [];
    entities = [];
    var cursor2 = db.coll2.find({_id:id});
    cursor2.forEach(function(x){
        if(x.intentions != undefined)
        {
            for( i = 0; i < x.intentions.length; i++)
            {
                var a = x.intentions[i];
                print(a);
                var arr = a.split("\"");
                print(arr);
                //cursor3 = db.coll3.find({_id:x.intentions[i]});
                //print(cursor3);
            }
        }
    })//cursor2
})//cursor
```

when I run this script as follows

/mnt/deployment/mongodb/mongodb-linux-x86_64-rhel62-3.4.2/bin/mongo db-name intentions.js

it gives me the following error:

> MongoDB shell version v3.4.2 connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/db-name MongoDB server version: 3.4.2 DBRef("Intention", ObjectId("5a3247206e4dee78d74b9e91")) 2019-03-11T05:41:50.251+0000 E QUERY [thread1] TypeError: a.split is not a function : Intentions.js:19:17 DBQuery.prototype.forEach@src/mongo/shell/query.js:501:1 Intentions.js:12:1 DBQuery.prototype.forEach@src/mongo/shell/query.js:501:1 Intentions.js:3:1 failed to load: Intentions.js

Comment: you have to use the `$split` operator in aggregation

Comment: @DakshMiglani but I'm writing separate javascript so how javascript would identify $split and I just want simply split the whole string. with double quotes as a separator.

Comment: Please add your cursor2  schema. what's the type of intentions?

Comment: @AZ_ intentions is of type array and each value of this array is of following format
DBRef("Intention", ObjectId("5a3247206e4dee78d74b9e91"))

Comment: ok, split is a method of string not of mongoDb id object, so your need is to get the value of id i.e. 5a3247206e4dee78d74b9e91 ?